# Efficiency in vector array manipulation

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I have a plotting subroutine that contains the following two steps. Im pretty sure this is not he most efficient implementation. The problematic steps are the following:

1)

```
dat = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {400000, 3}];
k=Dimension[dat][[1]]; 
z0=2.5;
Parallelize[list = Reap[Do[
    Sow[{dat[[n, 1]], dat[[n, 2]], dat[[n, 3]]/z0}];
    Sow[{dat[[n, 1]], dat[[n, 2]] - 1.154701, dat[[n, 3]]/z0}];
    Sow[{dat[[n, 1]] - 1., dat[[n, 2]] - 0.577350, 
      dat[[n, 3]]/z0}];
    Sow[{dat[[n, 1]] - 1., dat[[n, 2]] - 1.154701 - 0.577350, 
      dat[[n, 3]]/z0}];
    , {n, 1, k}]
   ][[2]][[1]];];
```

2)

```
regularPolygon[nbrSides_Integer?(# > 2 &), scale_:1]:= 
Polygon[scale{Sin[#], -Cos[#]} & /@ (2 Pi*Range[1/nbrSides, 1, 1/nbrSides])];

listhex = Reap[Do[If[
   Element[{list[[m, 1]], list[[m, 2]]},regularPolygon[6, 0.645497]] ==True,Sow[list[[m]]], 
   Continue], {m, 1, 4*k}]][[2]][[1]];
```

With the current dimensions of the array these step take a very long time.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Sure, so I have a set of vectors, the original data,I then make a larger list by doing 3 translation to the original set.I then use the regularPolygon to select the points inside a hexagon and then do a ListDensityPlot of that data at the end.

Comment: Your `regularPolygon` is equivalent to the built-in `Polygon@CirclePoints[{scale, 3 Pi/2 + 2 Pi/nbrSides}, nbrSides]`, or effectively equivalent to the simpler `Polygon@CirclePoints[{scale, 3 Pi/2}, nbrSides]`.  Or as a region, it's equivalent to `RegularPolygon[{scale, 3 Pi/2}, nbrSides]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`Parallelize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize) to do basic matrix operations is a terrible idea, because Mathematica already uses very effective parallelization under the hood for such operations. Here is an alternate approach for creating your `list` object. First, your data:

```
z0 = 2.5;
dat = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {400000, 3}];
```

Next, I would prepend each column with a 1. so that I can use [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) to construct your new lists:

```
datOne = Join[
    ConstantArray[1., {400000, 1}],
    dat,
    2
]; //AbsoluteTiming

datOne //Developer`PackedArrayQ
```

> {0.00737, Null}
>
> True

Note that the new matrix `datOne` is still packed. Now, here is a transformation matrix that will take an element `{a, b, c}` of `dat` and convert it into `{a - 1., b - .57735, c/z0}`:

```
tm3 = Developer`ToPackedArray @ N @ {{-1, -.57735, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1/z0}};
```

For example:

```
{{1,a,b,c}} . tm3
```

> {{-1. + 1. a, -0.57735 + 1. b, 0. + 0.4 c}}

So, to generate the 3rd [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow) of your step 1, you would just do:

```
s3 = datOne . tm3; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.004051, Null}

The other sows can be handled in the same way, and in my answer I will ignore them. You could just repeat this procedure 4 times with 4 different transformation matrices.

Now, for step 2. Instead of using `Element[point, region]` to test for region membership, it will be an order of magnitude faster to construct a [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction), and then apply that [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction) to all of your points: For example:

```
regularPolygon[nbrSides_Integer?(# > 2 &), scale_:1] := Polygon[
    scale{Sin[#], -Cos[#]} & /@ (2 Pi*Range[1/nbrSides, 1, 1/nbrSides])
];

rf = RegionMember[regularPolygon[6, .645497]]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.06491, Null}

Applying the [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction) to your data (notice that rf is **not** being mapped over the data points):

```
bool = rf[s3[[All, ;;2]]]; //AbsoluteTiming
Tally[bool]
```

> {0.025368, Null}
>
> {{False, 292548}, {True, 107452}}

To obtain the list of in-hexagon points you can use [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick):

```
listhex = Pick[s3, bool]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.189166, Null}

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @CarlWoll. A single plot when from 15 + min to 2.7 seconds. Huge improvement!

Comment: I did notice something when using my real data, even though is in the same format as dat, {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...}, it returns false when it checks for packedarray. I import my data from a text file and then make the array in the format I described. Do you know what is the issue?

Comment: Probably your data has a mix of integers and reals. You could always try something like ``ndat = Developer`ToPackedArray @ N @ dat`` and then see if ``Developer`PackedArrayQ @ ndat`` is true.

Comment: @CarlWollThat solved the problem, Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, `datOne = PadLeft[dat, {Automatic, 4}, 1.]` is about 5-10% faster than `Join` + `ConstantArray` -- practically negligible in this case though.  But it's also shorter to type and you can avoid having to input `Length@dat`. (+1)